# Display a picture via Django saved on mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I want to display a picture with Django, which is already saved on a mysql database. In all Methods I found people used `models.Imagefield(upload_to='path')`, but I think this will save the file into this directory and people from other computers won´t have access later.
So the question is, how do I access the database directly and display the picture without saving it in between?

I already managed to do this in python, but I am not quite sure how to implement the code into the `models.py`.
Something like this was my approach :

```
class mysqlpicture(models.Model):
    #mysqlpic=something?

    def openpic():
        connection = pymysql.connect(user='root', passwd='***',
                                     host='localhost',
                                     database='db')

        cursor = connection.cursor()

        sql1='select * from Pictures'
        cursor.execute(sql1)
        data=cursor.fetchall()

        mysqlpic=io.BytesIO(data[1][0])#one means second element of column zero 

        #img=Image.open(mysqlpic)
        #img.show()
        cursor.close()
        return mysqlpic
```

and then I tried in the `views.py` to give `mysqlpic`directly to the httpresponse like this:

```
def MysqlView(request):
    query_results = mysqlpicture.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('polls/pic.html')
    context = {
        'query_results': query_results,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

using a template `pic.html`to insert a picture like:

```html
{% for n in query_results %}
<mysqlpic src="{{ n.mysqlpic.url }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Has someone an idea how to to this in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BinaryField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) for this purposes.

But as stated in the django documentation:

> Although you might think about storing files in the database, consider that it is bad design in 99% of the cases.

```
from django.db import models

class MysqlPicture(models.Model):
    mysqlpic = models.BinaryField()
    # ...
```

And then to display in the template you can convert binary data to base64:

```
from base64 import b64encode

def mysql_view(request):
    query_results = MysqlPicture.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('polls/pic.html')
    context = {
        'images': [b64encode(obj.mysqlpic) for obj in query_results],
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Template:

```
{% for image in images %}
    <img src="data:;base64,{{ image }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How would I return the BinaryField then in the model, so that I can display the picture later?

Comment: @user8496104 convert your binary data to base64, for example. I updated the answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using *ImageField* does allow people from other computers to access it later. It inherits all attributes and methods from *FileField* which uploads the file into the server in the path specified in *upload_to* and also saves this path into your database to keep its reference. All of that happens when you call the *save()* method in your model instance.

Then, you can create the url to build a link by calling *your_instance.image_field.url* in your template. Also remember to have a look at [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-root) and [MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-url) which respectively tells Django the server root path for saving your files and the url that handles the media served from *MEDIA_ROOT*.

Comment: If only the path to the picture is stored on the database, wouldn't that mean that other people needed to communicate with my computer somehow to actually get the data of the picture, or what does it mean when the path is saved on the database?

Comment: Like Daniel said, it wouldn't mean that...The path saved in the database is related to a root path defined in MEDIA_ROOT. When you call _your_instance.image_field.url_ a link will be created in the format you specified in MEDIA_URL so that other users will be able to access the picture.